# How to sort the HashMap<String , Byte> by value in Android?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am developing in Android , and I want to sort the the `HashMap<String , Byte>`. It print the all value like the following code and log:

```
for (Object key : groups.keySet()) {
    Log.d("addGroup", "groups.get(key) = " + groups.get(key) + " , key = " + key);

}
```

And the log show like the following:

```
groups.get(key) = -6 , key = iii
groups.get(key) = -5 , key = qqq
groups.get(key) = -3 , key = bbb
groups.get(key) = -7 , key = xxd
groups.get(key) = -2 , key = kmn
groups.get(key) = -4 , key = hhh
groups.get(key) = -12 , key = yhn
groups.get(key) = -9 , key = 987
groups.get(key) = -13 , key = zxc
groups.get(key) = -10 , key = hxt
groups.get(key) = -11 , key = tfx
```

How to sort the HashMap by value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/109383/3788176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass your Hashmap to a Treemap
2. Use the Comparator class to define your ordering

Have a look here [Ordering HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579923/sorting-hashmap-by-value-using-a-treemap-and-comparator)